# why reload doesn't work with written from scratch class?

Tags: class, python-3.6, python-importlib

I'm running Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I'm writing an evolutionary algorithm, I translate the chromosome values to a class that has the evaluation function, but when I call the newly written class it doesn't update. I tried using reload, but it gives me an error. Help, please!

```
    def ddWriteStg(individual):
        stg= open('EvalInd.py','w')    
        stg.write('class EvalInd:\n\n')
        if individual[1]<individual[3]:
            fast=individual[1]
            slow=individual[3]
        else:
            slow=individual[1]
            fast=individual[3]    
        stg.write('\tdef loadParms(self):\n')
        stg.write('\t\tself._fast='+str(fast)+'\n')
        stg.write('\t\tself._slow='+str(slow)+'\n\n')
    
        stg.write('\tdef __init__(self):\n')
        stg.write('\t\tself.loadParms()\n')
        stg.write('\t\tpass\n')
    
        stg.write('\tdef evaluate(self):\n')
        stg.write('\t\treturn self._fast+self._slow\n')
        stg.close()
    
    import importlib
    def evaluateInd(individual):   
        ddWriteStg(individual) 
        from EvalInd import EvalInd
        importlib.reload(EvalInd)
        x=EvalInd()
        val=x.evaluate()
        return val
    
    ind=[1,47,1,52]
    a=evaluateInd(ind)
    print(str(a))
    ind=[1,60,1,80]
    a=evaluateInd(ind)
    print(str(a))
```

output: if I don't include the reload line, I get:
99
99
after I include the reload line:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 65, in <module>
        a=evaluateInd(ind)
      File "test.py", line 59, in evaluateInd
        importlib.reload(EvalInd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 139, in reload
        raise TypeError("reload() argument must be a module")
    TypeError: reload() argument must be a module
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A dear friend of mine helper me, and figured out in less than a minute the mistakes:

```
import EvalInd
x= EvalInd.EvalInd()
```

the changes above fix everything.